# Phantom payments periodically appearing from SagePay system

Tags: opayo

Really confused by this.  We have what is otherwise a working system, but every now and then (a few times a week) we get phantom payment reports (our system reports a user has made a payment, but no payment has been made) turning up on our system, sometimes referring to actual payments made weeks beforehand.

When a customer pays successfully, obviously they return to our successURL and the page logic processes that payment.  I have a watchdog on that page that writes an event log with the querystring used each time that page is hit, and on every single one of the phantom payment reports there is a corresponding entry on my event log, so it is being caused by the page being called.

Now... to me, it appears it's either the user reloading/returning to a page in their browser history still containing the querystring parameters OR it's SagePay somehow generating the page requests.  The problem with it being the user doing it, is that the entire page and payment system is contained within an iframe, so it's highly unlikely that our members (who aren't, as a rule, very technical) will be somehow finding the iframe URL and loading it manually, but it is possible I suppose.

Of course the problem with it being SagePay generating the requests is that the whole world would be having the problem, so I suspect it's down to our users and some peculiar combination of events/browsers.  Of course every user we contact flatly denies doing anything out of the ordinary and most don't even understand the questions we are asking them - it's just technically too far over their head.

Has anyone seen this kind of thing before?  Or is there a way we can try and trace this problem? I'm fairly new as a developer at this company so I'm only just coming to grips with how they've coded it and I don't like it at all, but it's very hard to change! In some circumstances, it appears that the system will accept the incoming page request + querystring as a valid return payment call from SagePay and the transaction gets written onto the file as a new payment, where none has actually been made.

I may have to build in a transaction number check, although we are limited by a third party database system we have to use and the field used to store the transaction ID is not indexed and there are MANY payments.

Comment: Do you have any plugins like ShareThis on the page? Sometimes they send urls back home and ping them later. You could check your server access log?

Comment: Nope - nothing like that.

Comment: I know this is a bit old, but I have had problems with a merchants using the non-iframe integration within an iframe. Are you using Server, sending Profile=LOW when you register the transaction?